# What is the most common sarcastic response to something you already know?

Tags: idioms, expressions, proverbs

How sarcastically imply someone who is trying to teach you something that you are well aware in that case

**Edited:**

I am going to find an up-to-date English metaphorical and sarcastic expression or proverb to indicate that someone who I am speaking to should not try to offer advice to me! Because comparing them, at that specific case, I am more experienced and aware about anything!

I have found two proverbs, but please let me know which one of them is in current use in the sense I am looking for:

> 1) [Don't teach an old dog new tricks.](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/you-can-t-teach-an-old-dog-new-tricks)
>   2)  [Don't teach your grandma how to suck eggs.](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/118200.html)

Answer (score 1):

I have some doubts about both of the expressions you list.

> Don't teach an old dog new tricks.

I haven't heard the old dog/new tricks expression used with this intent. Usually what people say is, "**You can't** teach an old dog new tricks." It means that someone is like an old dog, and that they are so set in their ways that they can't be flexible and adapt to a different way of doing things. I don't think you would apply this to yourself to indicate your expertise.

> Don't teach your grandma how to suck eggs.

I haven't heard this one at all, so I may be completely wrong here. In that case, I'm sure others will let me know ASAP. I have heard the expression "to suck", though, and it's not good. My boss once tried to explain to me the saying, "That dog sucks eggs.", and it wasn't that good either. So unless I had a knowledgeable authority to vouch for the grandma sucking eggs idiom, I would be careful of it.

But for a positive contribution: the situation you describe is exactly what "[mansplaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mansplaining)" is all about, except it only works when the advice  is given by a male to a more experienced and aware female, so it may not work for your purpose.

Comment: Thank you @Lorel C. Would it sound natural to you if someone says in a sarcastic manner: "are you "**are you mansplaining my own job to me?!**" or "**you don't need to mansplain my own job to me**."

Comment: "Don't teach your grandma how to suck eggs" appears to have the right meaning, but it's obsolete.  "mansplain" on the other hand, is almost the opposite, it's a  new word in the English language which could turn out to be a fad. Do you prefer to use such jargon as mansplain in your own speech? :-)

Comment: @A-friend , it's some sort of feminist term about how *men* are generally condescending to *women*, and not the other way around.

Comment: @A-friend the clue is in the word "man" in "mansplaining". Cambridge *explains* it well: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mansplain

Comment: @A-friend The 1st **especially when a man explains something to a woman** This implies arrogance and a typically sexist attitude. One could also argue that the expression itself is sexist, but it is clearly a criticism against some men who talk to adult women in a condescending way. The term is about sexism.